nanoFramework - using windows as a target with a USB to I2C converter
Is it possible to use nanoFramework with a USB top I2C serial converter so that it may be used on a Windows 10/11 client.
If so, is there a recommended hardware USB/I2C device.

Clarification please: you want to connect some I2C bus pins in a ESP32 to a Windows PC, is that it?

No, sorry. I want to connect slave devices - GPIO, ADC, environmental sensors to a windows PC (in the .NET C# environement). The I2C bus will be provided by the USB to I2C converter (I have an FTDI or an MCP2221A device available - but could select any other)

Currently, .NET nanoFramework offers I2C slave API for ESP32 targets.
There is no SPI slave, yet. Nor I2C slave for other platforms.

Thanks - that is what I thought from the docs, but wanted to make sure. It would be useful to support the Windows environment with a USB to I2C converter.

I didn't understand your comment above. .NET nanoFramework its about writing code for microcontrollers. In the use case that you've described, it would implement the I2C slave in the microcontroller (already supported in ESP32 platform), this one, in turn, would connect to that I2C to USB adapter which would be accessible to an application running on a Windows PC.

I got a reply from the nanoFramework folks, and indeed, as per your comment above,  there is no support for using the framework in windows to target I2C devices via a USB -> I2C converter (such as FT232H). Oh well, would have been nice.

.NET nanoFramework is to run on microcontrollers, not on Windows, so...
Nice people, those nanoFramework folks! :)
